# Mishebeirach for someone who doesn't want their mother's name used

Tags: tefilla, names, family-members, choleh-sick

Suppose someone really dislikes his mother and does not want to be known as (for example) "יוסף בן רחל". He's sick, and people wish to pray for him in a Mishebeirach.

Do his wishes have to be honored? And what is the alternative? יוסף בן שרה?

Comment: As always, consult your rabbi for practical advice rather than relying on the answers you see here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Rabbi I consulted said that for the sake of shalom, Sara could be used.

Comment: OK, that works for Shalom, but what about Chaim?

Comment: שלום שלום לרחוק ולקרוב

Comment: @Yishai שלום שלום ואין שלום