# MiSheBerach for someone who doesn't like his/her own name

Tags: tefilla, names, synagogue, choleh-sick

[Another question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26795/5) asked about a case in which someone does not want to use his/her mother's name in a MiSheBerach.

What if someone dislikes his/her own given name and goes by a different name? What name is used for a MiSheBerach?