# Using someone's mother/father's disliked name for ritual purposes

Tags: names, synagogue, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

Closely related to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26798/5), what happens if someone's mother or father doesn't/didn't like her or his name, and the child now either needs a MiSheBerach or is called to the Torah? What name should be used? Does Kibbud Av VaEim come into play?

(Note that, unless it is pointed out in the answers/comments that the rules are one and the same, I am asking only about ritualistic uses of the name, not legal uses. Hence [synagogue](/questions/tagged/synagogue).)